# What's your Favorite Extreme Feedback Device?

Tags: continuous-integration

We've probably all heard about the connecting lava lamps and [ambient orbs](http://www.ambientdevices.com/cat/orb/orborder.html) to your continuous integration systems. I was curious to know what other interesting things people are using or have heard of for extreme feedback devices?  Also, this [Tux Droid](http://www.kysoh.com/) seemed pretty sweet

Comment: Extreme Feedback Device sounds like a droid running up to you and punching you in the jaw.

Comment: ...but it is *not* the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 15):

An idea I have is to buy one of those [USB missile launchers](http://www.microplex.no/aspx/produkt/prdinfovnet.aspx?plid=45595) and write a program that can aim it at the stations of known users...

Comment: Or fire at the developer who broke the build. Hilarious.

Comment: Check out http://www.papercut.com/blog/chris/2011/08/19/who-broke-the-build/ for an example of missile launchers as Hudson/Jenkins feedback devices.

Comment: @JeffreyHulten I guess they read my answer!

Answer (score 9):

I like the system [Last.fm](http://blog.last.fm/2008/08/01/quality-control) uses. Along with antique analog devices to monitor server response time, loads of LCD displays, they also have red, yellow and green giant gummi bears to alert developers to broken builds. Makes me wish I had the time and money to set up similar stuff at work.

Answer (score 6):

At Agitar we tried [several feedback devices](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200404/20040401-eXtremeFeedbackForSoftwareDevelopment.html) and I'd say lava lamps have a unique characteristic to recommend them: it takes a while for the wax to melt.

That might seem like a small thing (and it is) but the effect as that it was a race by the team to fix the build before the wax would start moving.

However one thing we learned is you want two lamps, red and green, not a blue one like in the picture. Because having a lava lamp on is kind of nice so you shouldn't be denied that just because the build is good.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

A Batman sign on the office ceiling:

http://www.jensjaeger.com/2010/04/extreme-feedback-device-the-batman-lamp/

Answer (score 3):

Nothing beats the old nipple-crocodile-clip-rs232 combo.

Answer (score 3):

We at the Softwareschneiderei have several XFDs in place:
- a lamp (no lava)
- a portable fountain
- a led bar
- loudspeakers
- wall-mounted displays
- the infamous USB rocket launcher

you can read about them on our blog:
http://schneide.wordpress.com/category/extreme-feedback/

So far, we find the lamp the most useful, but the portable fountain is considered the "coolest" one. The led bar is the device needing the least explanation. The rocket launcher is battery powered and needs the most attention (reloading!).

This year, we introduce at least one new device.

Answer (score 3):

The [Nabaztag](http://www.nabaztag.com) rabbit is quite popular, especially because there are many interfaces developped (for example for Hudson server).

[alt text http://leblog.wcie.fr/.a/6a00d8341cb14e53ef0120a4ee0220970b-800wi](http://leblog.wcie.fr/.a/6a00d8341cb14e53ef0120a4ee0220970b-800wi)

Answer (score 2):

I've given thoughts to using one of [these](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/input/a85c/?cpg=ab)

Think: You broke the build, so your keyboard's glowing red until you fix it.

Sadly, last I checked, the utilities to change the kb's color were Windows only, so I'll never buy one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we've used [CruiseSaver](http://cruisesaver.sourceforge.net/), and threw it up on a huge wide-screen LCD monitor.

Edit:

Also, I was on a project where we put a Mr. Potatohead on the desk of the person who last broke the build.  It stayed there until someone else broke it, which might be 5 minutes or 5 weeks...

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl.NET + CCTray + Growl + Prowl = iPhone Push Notifications of when and who broke the build.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred is this one https://github.com/luismreis/beacon