# How do I configure an extreme feedback device to notify CI build status?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, extreme-feedback-devices

Trying to save the next guy/gal some trouble in finding out what is needed to setup lava lamps or traffic lights or what have you (the term I believe is [eXtreme Feedback Devices](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200404/20040401-eXtremeFeedbackForSoftwareDevelopment.html)) as a BIG VISIBLE INDICATOR of your continuous integration build status.

Ensure your post includes... (and please don't mess this question up with [imaginative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303614/whats-your-favorite-extreme-feedback-device/303901#303901) [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303614/whats-your-favorite-extreme-feedback-device/303728#303728).. although it may be insanely funny at the point of conception)

- the XFD
- what 'helper' hardware is needed
- software that you managed to hook it up with
- detailed instructions on how to set it up

Comment: Does anyone know how to setup an 'ambient org' ? thanks...

Answer (score 2):

There's actually pretty detailed directions for this kind of thing in the CruiseControl documentation for the [X10 Publisher](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#x10).

(Mike Clark's directions mentioned by Gishu predate the X10 publisher being part of the base CruiseControl distribution.)

Answer (score 2):

Dirk Ziegelmeier explains how he connected a led bar (the XFD) to CruiseControl.NET. He gives out the source code of his connection software, explains what hardware to buy and even the results of his reengineering on the device's protocol:
http://ziegelmeier.net/?q=XFD

In a more high-level explanation, we are talking about our XFDs, too:
http://schneide.wordpress.com/category/extreme-feedback/
But if somebody asks, we will provide more details, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I implemented a very easy and cheap (7$) build light. Read about it [here.](http://funagile.wordpress.com/) No custom hardware needed and the lamp can be ordered with free delivery worldwide.

Comment: The link 404s. Can you fix it? That was unusually quick for a link in an answer to die, but it illustrates why putting more content than just a link in your answer is important to ensure it has long term value in its own right.

Comment: hi, sorry about the 404. I moved the blog to wordpress, it should work better now. Had losts of problems with Websense from work... http://funagile.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/a-cheap-agile-lamp-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

### [Configuring dual lava lamps with CruiseControl (java)](http://www.pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/Devices/BubbleBubbleBuildsInTrouble.rdoc) (mike clark)

### [Configuring lava lamps (or traffic lights) with Microsoft TFS](http://www.tfsbuild.com/ControlLavaLampsAndStreetLights.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we solved it: LEDBLOA - http://www.therealjoshanderson.com/2010/04/ledbloa-ftw-my-teams-new-build-status.html

It's a pretty simple setup.  The LED sign is connected to a laptop via usb.  The laptop has a small app that simply parses the RSS feed our CI server produces.  We poll the feed and see if anything changed.  If so, we update the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://www.iprogrammable.com/2011/01/02/hudson-continuous-integration-led-message-board-monitor/

[image: Jenkins/Hundson USB Led Message Board CI State Monitor]

I've made it using 20$ USB LED Message Board device. It's hooked up to Jenkins/Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

It is *very* easy to user a parallel port to control a stacked status indicator.
They look like a pile of hockey puck-sized lenses  that light up. Usually used in factories. Attached to machines. Can be a bit pricey.
They have a RED light, a green light and etc... in a stack. Some talk to CAN buses, but the cheapo ones are just lights.
You get yourself a parallel port relay card, and an appropriate plug-pack(wall wart).
The easy thing is all you have to do is write a single letter to the parallel port.
Set bits turn on lights.

Not very "extreme" though,  (although the optional strobes and hooters are very attention-getting)

Because you don't need to do anything clever to the parallel port, it can be a USB parallel port.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.agiletoys.com sells a kit that includes a red beacon and x10 firecracker kit. Currently Cruise Control supports x10 and this is a great way to let the team know that the build is broken in a BIG VISIBLE way.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Lava will watch a Continuum or Cruise Control build server and send X10 signals appropriately to turn devices on and off.  It has reasonably good setup instructions.

Also here is an installer that will handle setting up RXTX on linux:  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/jmri/RXTX-install-5.tar.gz

Answer (score -3):

Here is another solution. We want long range visibility and used LED lights.

[www.mukthar.com/make-interesting-traffic-lights-continuous-integration-hudson-jenkins/](http://www.mukthar.com/make-interesting-traffic-lights-continuous-integration-hudson-jenkins/)

Comment: although the link is useful but please copy-paste the main ideas here, just in case if the link goes down.

Comment: Aaaand the link is down