# Any experience with a Continuous Integration Appliance?

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, hudson, appliance

We have a continuous integration server running [Hudson CI](http://hudson-ci.org/). I'm thinking about putting up an LCD display in the office with various build stats and am curious what others have put together.

I'm currently thinking about buying a WIFI-enabled digital picture frame that I can send generated images to. Or repurposing an old laptop...

Thoughts? Experiences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many solutions (all links below point to working solutions with Hudson or existing plugins):

- [Hudson Build Status Lava Lamps](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Build+Status+Lava+Lamps)
- [Hudson Ambient Orb](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/08/14/my-extreme-feedback-device)
- [Hudson Do It Yourself Orb](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/11/diyorb_my_own_e.html)
- ["Red Bear Alert!" - The Hudson Bear Lamps](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20250625)
- ["Watch the bikes!" - Extreme Feedback with Traffic Lights](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38633731)
- [Start to smell those code smells](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/smell-if-its-well/)
- [Nabaztag](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Nabaztag+Plugin)
- [TuxDroid](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/TuxDroid+Plugin)
- [Radiator View](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Radiator+View+Plugin) (ideal for displaying on a screen on the office wall)
- [eXtreme Feedback Panel](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin) (even better than the Radiator View, especially for a FullHD flat panel)

Check out the other [Build notifiers](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins#Plugins-Buildnotifiers) plugins for more ideas.

Personally, I have experienced the bunny, lava lamps, orbs and the radiator view. They all do the job but I have a little preference for the lava lamps. As Jeffrey mentioned in another answer, it's indeed funny to race against the wax to fix a build failure :)

Comment: That's an excellent list, Pascal :) I've recently released a new [Jenkins Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin), which you might also find useful for displaying on a screen on your office wall. I designed it to accommodate for different screen sizes, including big screen TVs. Give it a shot and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you do, please also purchase one of [these](http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/warfare/8a0f/) and program it such that it will detect who in your team breaks the build; aim itself at them, and shoot them.

But more seriously, a nice LCD with various displays is nice; but consider that if you use twitter, you may also like to have a twitterbot that tells all your staff the status of the builds (when the break; etc).

Answer (score 0):

Christoph De Baene has a nice wiretup of using [Continuous Integration with traffic lights](http://www.delarou.net/weblog/PermaLink,guid,e1a7193b-520e-47e1-9ea8-c15f7a4eff73.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this previous question: [What's your Favorite Extreme Feedback Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303614/whats-your-favorite-extreme-feedback-device)

Answer (score 0):

At my company someone build a rails or grails webapp creating such pages. With a frame page a cycle is created using javascript.

A former company i worked for, had a flashing light connected via an usb controlled extension lead to the cruise control server. A broken build turned the light on, fixed turned of - you can use different lights with different colors for multiple builds.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment permits it, you can use a sound system with different sounds to play when someone breaks the build. "D'oh!" from Homer Simpson, Darth Vader, sirens, all of them are just some examples of what you can do.

If you have access to developers machines, you can even create jokes like this sent to their desktops:

[image: Swine Flu Origin]

...obviously, with other context.

The best way to create these jokes is to use "Motivational Posts" with internal jokes they can understand. Every organization has internal jokes. You can use a [motivational generator](http://bighugelabs.com/motivator.php).

...again, this would be the "funny" approach. If you're into programming all these features, you can do a lot of stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [Lava Lamps](http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/BuildStatusUsingLavaLampsByKenNichols.aspx)? There is also project [ContinousLava](http://code.google.com/p/continuouslava/) - notification tool for integrations servers (Continuum and Cruise Control) - maybe in future for Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this nice article "[Who broke the build?](http://www.papercut.com/blog/chris/2011/08/19/who-broke-the-build/)"
which show how they use a USB Foam Missile Launcher.

The associated open source project to control the device is named [Retaliation](https://github.com/codedance/Retaliation).